# Finding small connected subgraphs of a random regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, regular-graph

Fix parameters $m,f,b$. I do not believe it matters for the general form of the question, but in the problem I am examining $m,f,b$ are all powers of $2$ with $m \gg f > b$. For example $m=2^{25},f=256,b=4$.

The problem statement can then be formulated as the following: given a random $f$-regular graph with $m$ verticies denoted $G$ find the smallest connected subgraph $H$ of $G$ such that $\mathsf{degree}(h) \geq b, \forall h \in H$.

In particular I am wondering if there are any results or intuition to be gained about how small we expect $H$ to be. Moreover, I was curious if there is some efficient algorithm to find a small (for some definition of small), but not necessarily the smallest, $H$ starting at a random vertex in $G$.

Comment: I think the [clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) is essentially a special case of your question, so finding an efficient algorithm may be difficult.